# Binding to other controlls InputBindings

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, inputbinding

I would like to Bind `Keybindings` of my `Button` to the `Keybindings`  of my `Window`.

My Window (`Name="Mainwindow`) Input Binding:

```
<Window.InputBindings>
    <KeyBinding Key="Return" Command="{Binding KeyPressed}" CommandParameter="Next"/>
</Window.InputBindings>
```

My idea of what the Button should look like

```
<Button Content="Select Directory" Command="{Binding BrowseDirectory}">
     <Button.InputBindings>
           <KeyBinding Key="Return" Command="{Binding ElementName=Mainwindow, Path=InputBindings}"/>
      </Button.InputBindings>
</Button>
```

Sadly the Outwindow did not display any kind of Binderror any anything else to give me a clue on why it is not working.
So baisically the question is: How can I Bind the `Control.InputBindings` to another `Control.InputBindings`?

Comment: if you have the keybinding on the window then the command will be triggered when the correct key is pressed, duplicating that on the button would be a waste of time

Comment: When the button is focused, the return button will fire the the button.clicked event --> it will start executing the command.

I am looking for a way to overcome this, for now i have decided to copy paste the stuff in <Window.InputBindings> to <Button.InputBindnigs>. Not pretty but does the job until i find time to search for the propper solution.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just bind the `Command` property to the same source property:

```
<Button Content="Select Directory" Command="{Binding BrowseDirectory}">
    <Button.InputBindings>
        <KeyBinding Key="Return" Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.KeyPressed, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}"/>
    </Button.InputBindings>
</Button>
```